# Running Docker Container on AWS

Tags: docker, amazon-ec2

I am learning docker and following the online tutorials at https://training.docker.com/self-paced-training

I have spun up an AWS-EC2 Ubuntu AMI. Have added HTTP and HTTPs to the security group. After using putty to SSH into the instance I ran the following command

```
docker run -d -p 8888:8080 tomat:8.0

docker ps gives me this
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                     NAMES
61d27e1ab2c4        tomcat:8.0          "catalina.sh run"   5 minutes ago       Up 5 minutes        0.0.0.0:8888->8080/tcp
```

Using my web browser when i try to http public_ip:8888 i get connection timed out.

```
netstat -lt on my instance gives me this
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State
tcp        0      0 *:ssh                   *:*                     LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 [::]:ssh                [::]:*                  LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 [::]:8888               [::]:*                  LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 [::]:32768              [::]:*                  LISTEN
```

What am i missing. why i cannot http into my tomcat container ?

Comment: Should the IPv4 port be opened as well as the IPv6? I'm not sure why you need a whole EC2 instance to learn docker

Comment: I'd recommend going to Amazon and learning about their container service directly because that seems to be the issue, not Docker.  https://aws.amazon.com/ecs/getting-started/

Comment: @cricket_007 This might be one of those "crawl before you can walk" things. Start out with running containers manually, understand what happens, realize how much of a pain it is to do it by hand, look for tools that make it easier. By the time you get to something like ECS, you what problems the abstractions they put in place are designed to solve.

Answer (score 1):

You've published port 8080 from the container to port **8888** on the host. If you log on to the EC2 instance and run `curl http://localhost:8888` you should see the response.

But your Security Group is only allowing HTTP (port 80) and HTTPS (port 443), so AWS is blocking traffic on port 8888. If you want to use a non-standard port, you'll need to open port 8888 in the security group.

Or instead, publish the container's port to standard HTTP:

```
docker run -d -p 80:8080 tomcat:8.0
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to open 8888 port in Security group then you will be able to access the application from internet.